# Child components not re-rendering after setState in Parent (props not assigned to state in child's constructor)... React seems broken (pure React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Soo I've looked up all the questions on this issue, and the people who run into the problem I'm running into set their child's props to the child's state, while I correctly call props in the child's render.

- I'm trying to make John Conway's Game of life in React using styled buttons
- I have a 2d boolean array set up in the Game component's state that's supposed to control the Square component (whether it uses the 'Alive' or 'Dead' CSS class)
- Whenever the game's state is updated the square component's state is not, I have console.log()s set up to show what's getting updated
- The parent's class name is Game and the child's class name is Square
- You can ignore the step() and countNeighbors() functions in Game
- I suspect the problem has to do with passing in a value from a large array into the child's props or generating the child props in a function

any words of advice are appreciated

Game component:

```
class Game extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            vals: [],
            squares: [],
        }
        this.state.vals = this.genVals();
        this.state.squares = this.genSquares();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
        console.log('Game component updated');
        console.log(this.state.vals);
    }

    handleClick(i, j) { //yes this works, it was brought up from the depths of google so don't delete it before being sure it doesn't work
        this.setState({
            vals: {
                ...this.state.vals,
                [i]: {
                    ...this.state.vals[i],
                    [j]: !this.state.vals[i][j],
                }
            }
        });
        console.log(this.state.vals[i][j])
    }

    genVals() {
        let ret = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            let row = []
            for(let j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
                row.push(false);
            }
            ret.push(row);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    genSquares() {
        let squares = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            let row = [];
            for(let j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
                let square = <Square key={i + ',' + j} isAlive={this.state.vals[i][j]} handleClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, i, j)} 
                />; //pass what I want to control squares with down the props
                row.push(square);
            }
            squares.push(row);
        }
        return squares;
    }

    renderSquaresList() {
        let list = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            list.push(<li key={i}>{this.state.squares[i]}</li>);
        }
        return <ul>{list}</ul>;
    }

    countNeighbors(i, j) { //many equivalent ways to approach this problem, I'm picking the simplest to read
        let count = 0;
        let squares = this.state.vals;

        //need to check boundaries since js throws a fit trying to read null/undefined objects instead of just implicitly delcaring falsy
        let topOk = (i > 0) ? true: false; //i is -y and j is x 
        let bottomOk = (i < 50) ? true: false;
        let leftOk = (j > 0) ? true: false;
        let rightOk = (j < 50) ? true: false;

        //count neighbors bottom to top (order is arbitrary)
        if(bottomOk && squares[i + 1][j])
            count++;
        if(bottomOk && rightOk && squares[i + 1][j + 1])
            count++;
        if(bottomOk && leftOk && squares[i + 1][j - 1])
            count++;
        if(rightOk && squares[i][j + 1])
            count++;
        if(leftOk && squares[i][j - 1])
            count++;
        if(topOk && squares[i - 1][j])
            count++;
        if(topOk && rightOk &&squares[i - 1][j + 1])
            count++;
        if(topOk && leftOk && squares[i - 1][j - 1])
            count++;

        return count;
    }

    step() {
        console.log(this);
        for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            for(let j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
                //console.log(this.squares[i][j]);
                let count = this.countNeighbors(i, j);
                //console.log(count);
                if(count == 3 || (count == 2 && this.state.vals[i][j])) { //I dont need the triple = because I know what types I'm dealing with
                    this.state.vals[i][j] = true;
                    this.forceUpdate(); //words cannot describe the stress of getting this code to work
                }
                else {
                    this.state.vals[i][j] = false;
                    this.forceUpdate();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                {this.renderSquaresList()}
                <button onClick={this.step.bind(this)}>Step</button>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 0, 0)}>Test</button>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Square component (child prop):

```
class Square extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
        console.log('Square component updated, is it alive? ' + this.props.isAlive);
    }

    render() {
        let className = "Dead";
        if(this.props.isAlive) {
            className = "Alive";
        }
        return (
            <button onClick={this.props.handleClick} className={className}></button>
        );
    }
}
```

CSS class:

```
.Alive {
    background-color: #e8e129;
    border: none;
    color: none;
    padding: 10px 10px;

}

.Dead {
    background-color: #061244;
    border: none;
    color: none;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    line-height: 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [update child component when parent component changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44314799/update-child-component-when-parent-component-changes)

Comment: It seems that issue was because the person tried to assign a value to his component's props, I'm only trying to read them

Comment: abusing `setState` is not an issue - direct state mutations in `step`

Comment: I haven't gotten out to fixing `step` yet, is `handleClick` doing that aswell?

Comment: you can't `console.log` setState-d values in the next line (read docs!) - use setState's callback (2nd arg) or console log in render

Comment: re reading this code after you said that there's definitely a few `console.log`s on here that need to be cut out